# .NET Core Middleware is not invoked

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket, .net-core, middleware

Hello i have the following problem:

I am trying to send an object from a `Console Application` to a `ASP NET Core Server` via `websockets`.

On the `Console` application i serialize an object with `NewtonSoft Json`and i send it over the `Socket` to the .NET Core server.

On the  Server i have created a tiny middleware.The   `Invoke` method just does not get called.
I keep two instances of visual studio open and nothing happens on the server side,until i close the connection on the client side and this error pops in on the server side - terminal :
[image]

1 **Server**

1.1 **Program**

```
    class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                BuildWebHost(args).Run();
            }
            public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)=>

                WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseSockets()
                .UseUrls("http://localhost:8200")

                .Build();
        }
```

1.2 **Startup class**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddSingleton<WebSocketService>(x=>new WebSocketService());

        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {

            builder.UseWebSockets();
            builder.UseMiddleware<SocketMiddleware>();


        }
    }
```

1.3 **Middleware**

```
class SocketMiddleware
    {
        WebSocketService handler;
        public SocketMiddleware(WebSocketService _handler,RequestDelegate del)
        {
            this.handler = _handler;
            this.next = del;
        }

        RequestDelegate next;

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {


            if (!context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                await  this.next(context);
                return;
            }
            await this.handler.AddClientAsync(context.WebSockets);

        }
    }
```

Note: I will not post code of the service that the middleware uses since it is not relevant in this case.The `invoke` does not get called.

2 **Client**

The client just serializes a POCO class `Player`  and sends it over the socket.It then waits for the server to respond with a list of `Player`.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Player updatePlayer = new Player(100);
            List<Player> players;
            Memory<byte> buffer = new byte[2000];
            ReadOnlyMemory<byte> toSend;
            ReadOnlyMemory<byte> actualReceived;
            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint iPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8200);
            Random rand = new Random();

            await socket.ConnectAsync(iPEndPoint);
            using(NetworkStream stream =new NetworkStream(socket))
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    updatePlayer.Lat = rand.Next(10, 100);
                    updatePlayer.Lng = rand.Next(10, 100);

                    string data=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updatePlayer);
                    toSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
                    await stream.WriteAsync(toSend);

                    int received=await stream.ReadAsync(buffer);
                    actualReceived = buffer.Slice(0, received);
                    string msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(actualReceived.ToArray());
                    players = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Player>>(msg);
                    if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }


        }
```

**P.S** Could it be a problem that the server uses `websockets` and on the client i use the `socket` class?I figure as long as the destination address and port are okay..its just bytes.

Comment: *“I will not post code of the service that the middleware uses since it is not relevant in this case.”* – Not sure I agree with that. Your middleware request is being interrupted, so it does kind of matter how you are interacting with the web socket request.. That being said, are you sure your client works? Did you try using a browser instead? Also, is there any more in the logs?

Comment: I have tried the websocket client provided by chrome and it works.Also i have tried with a angular 2 js client and it still works.The `Invoke` method gets invoked.Why is it that the `console application` won't invoke it ? I suppose that it could be that i send raw `Tcp` and the .NET framework expects a `HTTP GET` ?

Comment: Did you check the [WebSocket specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455)? WebSockets are not just bare TCP sockets, they are an upgrade of a HTTP connection, so you cannot just open up a socket like that and expect to be able to send data.

Comment: Yes i am aware of the fact that first you send a HTTP request that will get upgraded to websocket (raw tcp).But how do you wrap your request to do that? I mean coming with a raw socket how should that be dealt with in C# ?

Comment: If you want to use a raw TCP socket, you will have to implement the protocol yourself. Otherwise, you should probably use a WebSocket client library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **Server.cs** the `Invoke` *method* has a parameter of type `WebSocketManager`.
We can accept a `WebSocket` connection but not a raw `Socket`.
Therefore in the **Client.cs** i replaced the raw `Socket` with a `WebSocket` implementation.